# Assume $a_n > 0$ and $\lim(n^2a_n)$ exists. Show that $\sum a_n$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

**Theorems and Facts I'll be assuming:**

*Note: Assume all series mentioned are being summed from index 1 to $\infty$.

- **Theorem A**: Assume $\lim(a_n) = a$. If $a_n \geq 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $a \geq 0$.
- **Theorem B** (Comparison Test): Assume $(a_k)$ and $(b_k)$ are sequences satisfying $a_k, b_k \geq 0$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and there exists some $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_k \leq b_k$ for all $k \geq M$. If $\sum b_k$ converges, then $\sum a_k$ converges.
- **Theorem C**: If $\sum a_k = A$, then $\sum ca_k = cA$ for all $c \in \mathbb{R}$.
- **Fact A**: $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges.

**Proof**:

Let $\lim(n^2a_n) = l$. Since $a_n > 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$,  $n^2a_n > 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. By Theorem A, $l \geq 0$.

Let $\epsilon = l + 1$. Then there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq N$,
$$|n^2a_n - l| < \epsilon$$ $$\Rightarrow -l - 1 < n^2a_n-l < l+1 $$
$$\Rightarrow -1<n^2a_n <2l+1$$ $$\Rightarrow n^2a_n < 2l+1$$ $$\Rightarrow a_n < \frac{2l+1}{n^2}.$$

We know $\sum \frac{2l+1}{n^2}$ converges by Fact A and Theorem C.

Since $\sum \frac{2l+1}{n^2}$ converges, $\sum a_n$ converges by Theorem B.

Comment: Looks fine. This is a special case of the [Limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test).

Comment: For $n$ large enough $n^2a_n<C$ for some constant $C>0$. Then $a_n=n^2 a_n/n^2\leq C/n^2$. The conslcusion follows by comparison test.